# Finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android

i followed the guidelines on how to setup using exactTarget Android Library following this http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/journey-builder-for-apps/sdk-implementation/register-your-devices.html#android-androidstudio

When i run my application i get the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':myproject:dexProductionDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

here is the full stack trace

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

:myproject:dexProductionDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myproject:dexProductionDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myproject:dexProductionDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1196)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:151)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$5$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$5$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
    ... 60 more



BUILD FAILED
```

Here is my gradle build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        maven { url 'http://www.testfairy.com/maven' }
        maven { url "http://exacttarget.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository" }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.testfairy.plugins.gradle:testfairy:1.+'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'testfairy'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

dependencies {

    compile(name: 'etsdk-3.5.0', ext: 'aar')

// 3rd Party Libraries Required for SDK integration
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.4"
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest'
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest'
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'

    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {

    }

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.5'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by increasing and enabling mulitDex size on the gradle build

Comment: Beginning with the 4.0 release of the SDK all 3rd party libraries have been removed from our SDK.  This effort in addition to the changes Google made to Google Play Services has dramatically decreased our method signature footprint.